# How do I cd up and down again with symlinks in bash?

Tags: bash, symlink, cd-command

Structure:

```
/base/
   +- somedir/
   +- symlink/  -> /some_other_dir
```

This command (in addition to my Makefiles) fails:

```
cd /base/symlink
ls ../somedir
```

Bash complains that ../somedir does not exist. Likewise, my makefiles in some_other_dir that reference ../somedir fail. However, cd .. works just as expected. Can I have my shell act with regards to the logical structure?

Comment: You mean `cd ../somedir` works, while `ls ../somedir` does not, right? I could reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @Bernhard: that is correct. This also breaks some more complex commands in my Makefile.

Comment: sure you don't have a broken symlink. This workflow fine on my system. Did I get your example correct?

  [code]
  /tmp # ls -ld {bob,tom}
  drwxr-xr-x 3 scott scott 4.0K Jan 16 12:29 bob
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 scott scott    3 Jan 16 12:29 tom -> bob

  /tmp # cd tom
  /tmp/tom # ls
  dir  file
  /tmp/tom # ls ../bob
  dir  file
  [/code]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`..` is a directory entry in the current directory. It is a hardlink to the directory one level up.  `/base/symlink/..` is actually the same file as `/some_other_dir/..`, and it is `/` (unless `some_other_dir` is itself also a symlink to somewhere else).

In most shells, `cd` treats `..` specially, that is instead of treating it as the `..` directory entry, occurrences of `..` are interpreted by `cd` (and not by the system's pathname resolution) as removing one level of directory.

As an example, in `cd a/b/..`, the shell does a `chdir("a")` instead of doing a `chdir("a/b/..")`. To get the latter, you need to do `cd -P a/b/..`.

It's important to realise that it only applies to `cd` (and only in *some* shells), (IMO, a misfeature), not to `ls` or `vi` or anything else (unless that *anything else* is a script of those shells that passes those paths to `cd` without `-P`).

In those shells where `cd` does that *logical* interpretation of `..`, the `pwd` builtin and the `$PWD` variable contain the *logical* current directory instead of the real (physical) one, that is one with possibly symlink directory components. Similarly, you can use `pwd -P` to get the *physical* working directory.

Now, if you want to do

```
cd /A/b
anything-but-cd ../c
```

And actually mean:

```
anything-but-cd /A/c
```

Regardless of whether `/A/b` was a symlink or not, you could do instead:

```
anything-but-cd "$(dirname -- "$PWD")/c"
```

or

```
anything-but-cd "${PWD%/*}/c"
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
anything-but-cd $PWD:h/c
```

To remove 3 `/*`s off the end of `$PWD`:

```
anything-but-cd "${PWD%/*/*/*}/c" # POSIX
anything-but-cd $PWD:h:h:h/c      # zsh
```

Comment: Could somebody explain / link what the `PWD%/*` means? — `dirname -- "$PWD"` is clear enough, but it only helps when the _lowermost_ directory is symlinked. If I'm in `rd/sl/rd/rd` and would like to get out, I would need to know exactly at which level the symlink is and explicitly treat that, whereas `cd ../../../..` does that automatically.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, run `info bash param` for instance. To get to the section about parameter expansion in the bash manual. To strip more than one `/*` from the end of `$PWD`, you can do `${PWD%/*/*/*}` (here for 3). Or in `zsh`/`csh`: `$PWD:h:h:h`