# How does cd .. know which directory is ..?

Tags: cd-command

Drectories contain `.` and `..` which are hard links to the current and parent directory.

So how does the shell know for example in the prompt, that the current directory is called "a" in `cd a/path/..`? Does it have special casing for this?

Otherwise from its perspective, isn't it entering a directory called `..`, rather than knowing that this directory is also the directory above? How does it know the name?

Comment: `ls -a` if you look then both `.` and `..` exist in the current directory.

Comment: The directory entry `..` refers to the parent directory. To change to the 'previous' directory you can use `cd -`

Comment: @Lambert What does that have to do with the question ?

Comment: @JID, I hope it clarifies that `..` is not a hardlink to the previous directory as stated by James.

Comment: @Lambert he obviously meant the parent, don't be pedantic.

Comment: @JID  the details matter, I think the pedantry is warranted.

Comment: @ChrisDown That is the most confusing sentence i have ever read.

Comment: @pdo The context was enough to understand, it was unnescesary to answer the question.

Comment: @OP This may help you understand http://www.slashroot.in/inode-and-its-structure-linux

Comment: @JID In which case, allow me to try again: I think the question is asking about the following: `cd foo/bar; cd ..` -- this results in the shell stating the directory is "foo" in the prompt, but how does it know that `cd ..` went to the same directory as "foo"?

Comment: @ChrisDown Look at my link

Comment: @JID Do you have a specific part that you want the OP to look at? inodes don't store name information -- the answer doesn't lie there. While `cd ..` doesn't need to know any name information, the shell does have to take some special casing to know that `..` == `foo`.

Comment: @ChrisDown Yes it uses the inode instead,both `foo` and `..` have the same inode, did you even read what i linked? Read the bit that says `Inode Structure of a Directory:`

Comment: @JID I'm quite aware of how an inode works, thanks. Yes, they have the same inode, but there is no inode -> file mapping present in the filesystem, only file -> inode. As such, special casing is needed.

Comment: @ChrisDown clearly you don't

Comment: You might find these interesting: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79621 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61513

Answer (score 4):

I assume that your question is how bash can know to change the directory so that the working directory is `foo` (rather than `foo/bar/..`) in `cd foo/bar/..`.

While these two paths will be are represented by the same inode (unless there are symlinks present in the path, as shown at the end of this answer), the shell does need to take special measures to show the current directory name as `foo`, rather than `..`. In `bash`, when `cd` encounters `..` in the path, it internally just strips the parent directory away, meaning that `..` can never be the directory name.

This is documented in `help cd`:

> `..` is processed by removing the immediately previous pathname component back to a slash or the beginning of DIR.

This special casing results in the following interesting behaviour (note that `foo/qux/..` still resolved to `foo`, even when the real path was `bar/baz/..`):

```
$ tree
.
|-- bar
|   `-- baz
`-- foo

3 directories, 0 files
$ ln -s "$(readlink -f bar/baz)" foo/qux
$ tree
.
|-- bar
|   `-- baz
`-- foo
    `-- qux -> bar/baz

4 directories, 0 files
$ cd foo/qux/..
$ basename "$(pwd)"
foo
```

Comment: `foo/bar/..` is `foo`, they have the same inode. It has absolutely nothing to do with cd. Any command will work.Try ls -id `foo/bar/..` and ls -id `.`. It uses the inode and the inode is the same.

Comment: @JID I think you're missing the point of the question being asked -- `foo/bar/..` and `foo` are *the same inode*, but they are not *the same path*. The shell has to make special considerations to declare the path as `foo` rather than `foo/bar/..`.

Comment: It doesn't have to make any considerations, it just gets the inode for whatever you call, the filenames/directories are just for the user to look at.

Comment: @JID That's the point -- the filename being presented to the user by the shell is not `..`, but `foo`, and the shell can only know that this is so by special casing. The shell *does* have to special case finding the filename for the user to look at from somewhere, as there's no inode -> filename mapping, only filename -> inode.

Comment: RIghtttt, i think i understand what you are saying now,I interperet the question differently, as in How does it know where to go, rather than how does it get the name. But you have answered purely in the context of how cd changes `PWD`,etc. But yeah I understand what you're saying now :)Would have been nice for OP to have given some clarification or any comment at all !

Comment: `foo/bar/..` and `foo` may not be the same inode if `foo` or `foo/bar` are symlinks.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for your note! I'd neglected to think about that, I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `..` is a hard link to the parent directory. The shell does not need to know the name of the directory when accessing `..`; it simply accesses the directory through the inode.

An inode is a structure that stores all metadata of the file (or directory), except the file's name: type, permissions, owner, group, size, access/change/modification/deletion times, number of links, attributes, ACLs, and address where the actual file content (i.e. the data) is stored.

Comment: That's not true of `cd` (in most shells except the Bourne shell), that does a _logical_ handling of `..` regardless of the `..` hard link. You need `cd -P` for `cd` to chdir into the `..` directory. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61513